# How to split MTS files?

Tags: video, file-formats, software-recommendation

I have a bunch of large HDTV .MTS files from a camera. I want to cut them in many parts, preferably with free software.

How?

Comment: Relevant: http://superuser.com/questions/479111/cut-smart-edit-mts-avchd-progressive-files-un-ubuntu-lucid

Comment: Hello Pavel, and welcome to Stack Exchange. To get any reliable answers for your questions, can you please add some details to your question? We need to know things like what OS you are using, what file size the files are (is large 2GB, or 20GB?), what sort of file you want after editing (more .mts files, or something web-ready etc.). When we have a detailed question, we can give great answers. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use ffmpeg to split them programmatically or use [LightWorks](http://www.lwks.com/) to cut them manually with a GUI.